# Acyclic across cuts in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Given we have a graph G = (V,E) and a subset F with only V in it, for each connected component S of F, add the minimum weight edge in the cut (S, V \ S) to F.

Why is it that every time the minimum weight edge is added to F, F remains acyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create cycle, you have to create edge which connects vertices which are already connected.

If you add edge between vertices that are not connected, you don't create new cycle. You connect two unconnected components. But graph remains acyclic.

To get better understanding how it works, you could represent connected component of graph as single vertex. And then, when your add edge between unconnected components, your just merge vertices.

By the way, this question is not related to weights (and MST algorithm). It's still valid without weights.